# GitHub Packages 404 for maven-metadata.xml / does it support dynamic version resolution?

Tags: maven, gradle, github, github-package-registry

Has anyone managed to get Maven dynamic version resolution working with GitHub packages?

I want to be able to declare a dependency with a dynamic version and have it resolved, like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.example:my-package:1.+'
}
```

Under the covers, Gradle (and Maven too, I assume), uses the information inside a file called `maven-metadata.xml` which contains details of which packages & versions exist in the repository to resolve the dynamic version to a particular version (e.g. `1.+` might resolve to `1.1.2`).  However, when I publish to GitHub Packages, the Gradle logs show that the `maven-metadata.xml` file resource does not exist, so it uploads a new one without error.  However, when I try and curl that file, I get a 404 (meaning I am either publishing and GitHub is silently dropping the file, or the file is inside GitHub and is not visible to me after publishing).

```
// inside the Gradle debug logs, showing successful upload
14:43:16.332 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Upload https://maven.pkg.github.com/ORG/REPO/com/example/group/artifact-id/maven-metadata.xml' completed
```

This gives a 404 (when it should either resolve to a file or give me a redirect that I can follow with a `-L` flag on the `curl` command):

```
curl -X GET -v -H 'Authorization: token <some token here>' https://maven.pkg.github.com/ORG/REPO/com/example/group/artifact-id/maven-metadata.xml
```

Here is my repository configuration closure for dependency resolution; I use an identical one for publishing using the `maven-publish` plugin inside a `publishing{}` closure.

```
repositories {
    maven {
        name = "GitHubPackages"
        url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/ORG/REPO")
        credentials {
            username = 'some-user'
            password = 'github-token-with-repo-scope'
        }
    }
}
```